# Linux Kernel Remote Debugging using KGDB : GDB does not recognize functions?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, kernel, kgdb

I cross compiled the kernel sources for arm, with debug info and KGDB.

When I run gdb in the host :

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb vmlinux

...

Reading symbols from vmlinux... done.

(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0

Remote debugging unsing /dev/ttyUSB0

**0xc0080480 in ?? ()**
```

When I try to set breakpoints in functions, GDB says
that it doesn't recognize the function .For example :

```
(gdb) b panic
**Function "panic" not defined**
```

HELP Please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the right vmlinux file? check that and you can use `readelf -s` command on vmlinux file to check if your symbol is defined in it.